# Setting numpy array values to NaN based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working with a dataset where non existent values show up as a negative number. I want to convert these values to np.nan values but I can't figure out how. The condition for this is `(array < 0)`.

An example of what would happen to the array would be:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[-1,  1, -1,  1],
                  [ 1, -1, -1,  1],
                  [ 1, -1, -1, -1]])
```

To then be converted to:

```
np.array([[np.nan,      1, np.nan,      1],
          [     1, np.nan, np.nan,      1],
          [     1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])
```

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`np.nan` is a float so you need to convert `array` to float before doing the [boolean masking](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

```
isinstance(np.nan, float)  # True

array = array.astype(float)
array[array < 0] = np.nan
array
```

outputs

```
array([[nan,  1., nan,  1.],
       [ 1., nan, nan,  1.],
       [ 1., nan, nan, nan]])
```